# Webscraping site ReclameAqui

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, request

I was attempting to gather links from the ReclameAqui website. However, the site utilizes dynamic loading, which, after accessing the site, updates to an open page after a while using JavaScript. The return links are consistently the same, which hampers my web scraping efforts. I employed these technologies: Requests, Requests-HTML, and Selenium. Requests yielded the most satisfactory results due to its data collection speed. The website is https://www.reclameaqui.com.br/empresa/clear-corretora-de-valores/lista-reclamacoes/?pagina=1&status=NOT_ANSWERED.

The code used with Selenium is provided in the previous message. I need to access the correct links for web scraping. If I use Selenium to click on the information from page 13 onwards, it freezes and doesn't load the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# Solicite ao usuário o número de páginas que deseja coletar
num_paginas = 5

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True 

# Inicialize o driver do Chrome sem especificar o caminho para o ChromeDriver (se estiver no PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

try:
    for pagina in range(1, num_paginas + 1):
        # Navegue para a página da web com o número de página variável
        driver.get(f"https://www.reclameaqui.com.br/empresa/clear-corretora-de-valores/lista-reclamacoes/?pagina={pagina}")

        time.sleep(4)

        # Aguarde até que a classe específica esteja presente na página
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.sc-1pe7b5t-0.iQGzPh')))

        # Extraia e imprima os elementos com a classe "sc-1pe7b5t-0.iQGzPh"
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.sc-1pe7b5t-0.iQGzPh')
        for element in elements:
            print(element.text)  # Imprimir o texto dentro do elemento
            
        

        # Extraia o número de vezes que a classe se repete
        count = len(elements)

        # Extraia e imprima os links associados à classe
        for element in elements:
            link_element = element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
            link = link_element.get_attribute('href')
            print(f'Link: {link}')

        print(f'Número de vezes que a classe se repete na página {pagina}: {count}')

except ValueError:
    print("Número de páginas inválido.")

finally:
    # Feche o navegador
    driver.quit()
```